# Python asyncio/aiohttp: What are the requirements regarding BaseProtocol.connection_lost()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BaseProtocol.connection_lost) for `connection_lost` states:

> connection_made() and connection_lost() are called exactly once per successful connection.

Further down there's also the following state machine:

> start -> connection_made() [-> data_received() *] [-> eof_received() ?] -> connection_lost() -> end

Also, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BaseTransport.close) for `BaseTransport.close()` states:

> After all buffered data is flushed, the protocol’s connection_lost() method will be called with None as its argument.

and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.WriteTransport.abort) for `WriteTransport.abort()` states:

> The protocol’s connection_lost() method will eventually be called with None as its argument.

This seems to me to indicate the following responsibilities:

1. The transport *must*, if it has called `connection_made()`, later also call `connection_lost()` on the protocol (regardless of whether the connection is lost because of a call to `close()`, a call to `abort()` or an issue with the underlying connection).
2. The protocol *must not* assume that I/O has finished when a call to `close()` or `abort()` returns. It must wait for the call to `connection_lost()`. In particular, after `close()` or `abort()` returns, there may be work relating to the transport still scheduled on the event loop.

With that in mind, consider the following trivial aiohttp client program, using SSL:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
        async with session.post('https://whatevs/') as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Running this on my (windows) machine appears to work
correctly. However, if I put breakpoints or print statements into the
`connection_made()` and `connection_lost()` methods of aiohttp's
`ResponseHandler` class (a protocol implementation), I see that
`connection_made()` is called but `connection_lost()` is not.

The transport used is `_SSLProtocolTransport`, defined in asyncio's
`sslproto.py` file. Its `close()` method *is* called, and it sets off
a shutdown process. Due to the nature of SSL this shutdown process is
necessarily asynchronous, and the expectation appears to be that once
the shutdown is complete the `SSLProtocol` underlying the
`_SSLProtocolTransport` would, from its `_finalize()` method, close
*its* underlying transport. This would then cause a call to
`connection_lost` to bubble up the stack. However, none of this
asynchronous stuff actually happens. aiohttp appears to just call
`close()` and immediately discard the `_SSLProtocolTransport` (the
method where it does this is not even a coroutine), and the transport
never progresses with its shutdown sequence and never calls
`connection_lost()`.

So my question is: is this a bug in aiohttp and/or aysncio's SSL
protocol/transport, or am I misinterpreting the documentation as
regards the responsitilities of the transport and protocol?

## Why I'm Asking This

The reason for this question is that I have written an SSL transport
of my own, to allow me to use PyOpenSSL with asyncio, instead of the
standard library `ssl` module. In my implementation, after the call to
my `close()` method returns, there are still callbacks queued on the
event loop (scheduled with `call_soon()`). This is necessary in order
for the asynchronous shutdown sequence to be performed correctly, and
I expect the protocol to give my transport a chance to complete the
process and call `connection_lost()`.

When I use my transport with aiohttp, the `__aexit__` method of the
`ClientSession` created in the code above calls its own `close()`
method (not a coroutine), which causes my transport to be closed,
without waiting for `connection_lost()`. The event loop is then closed
and the module finalised while the transport is still alive and
performing I/O, resulting in a variety of errors.

I'm trying to figure out whether this is my fault or a bug in aiohttp
(and perhaps also asyncio's SSL transport). If it's my fault, I need
to know how I'm supposed to perform this asynchronous shutdown. I
could in principle handle it at the top level by running the event
loop until it's empty before calling loop.close(), but I don't see any
way to do that (there's `Task.all_tasks()` but that doesn't work for
things scheduled with `call_soon`). Even if I can do that somehow, it
would seem exceptionally ugly and is certainly not described as a
standard requirement for shutting down after such work in any
documentation I've seen for asyncio or aiohttp.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an issue in aiohttp bug tracker and copy your question into it.
IMHO Stack Overflow is not the best place for discussing questions like this.

Comment: So you think it's a bug in aiohttp? If so, that's an answer to the question, which is a generic one about the requirements on transports and protocols in asyncio. I don't want to submit a bug report to aiohttp if it's doing nothing wrong. As I explained, these errors only occur when I use my own transport and my immediate suspicion is that I've coded it wrong.

Comment: Further investigation reveals that in the trivial case above the underlying `_SelectorSocketTransport` is actually leaked because `close()` is never called on it, so `remove_reader()` is never called. The transport remains alive in a reference cycle with the event loop until the runtime is shut down. That is very definitely wrong, so I think this is unarguably a bug in aiohttp. I'll raise an issue for it.

Comment: Well, it's a bug in *something* - whether it's in aiohttp or asyncio isn't 100% clear