# ClientPayloadError when reading responses

Tags: aiohttp

I am getting a ClientPayloadError when reading data from a server.  The data is JSON.  I am using python 3.6.5 and aiohttp 3.4.4

On debugging it seems that there is a close connection detected, and upon getting that aiohttp tries to see if it was done reading, and since it wasn't it throws this exception.

I was reading the data using

await response.text()

But I tried to change it to reading the response from content in chunks and see if that makes the problem go away but I had the same issue.

So what I am wondering is if there is something going on where the wrong connection is being closed.  Maybe a connection I was done reading on is getting closed and a connection that's still not finished with its data is getting that signal ? Is that possible ?   It seems like perhaps something mentioned here:
[Python asyncio/aiohttp: What are the requirements regarding BaseProtocol.connection_lost()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154656/python-asyncio-aiohttp-what-are-the-requirements-regarding-baseprotocol-connect)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the answer was ultimately in calling JSON decode in the async portion of the code.  That was a blocking operation.  So something was timing out a transport layer while the decoding took place.  I took that operation out of the async portion and it seems to work.

But ultimately, I don't know what was timing out.  Would be good to know.

This seems to work:

return_data = await response.text()

And then I decode the return data in a synchronous part of the code.  The weird thing is that response.json() didn't work (or caused the same problem)...but I thought that would have been ok since it came from the same package.